# How to make a 'sticky' header in javascript at a certain scrolltop?

Tags: javascript

I want to add in my website a header at a certain scrolltop, I'm very suck in JS and I need Help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have some Javascript code to do scroll events. The best way to do this is to set a new CSS class for the fixed position to the header div when scrolling goes past a certain value that is checked through JS.

HTML

```
<div class="sticky"></div>
```

CSS Style

```
.fixedHeader {
    position: fixed;
    top:0; left:0;
    width: 100%; }
```

jQuery Code

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
  var sticky = $('.sticky'),
      scrollAmt = $(window).scrollTop();

  if (scrollAmt >= 100) sticky.addClass('fixedHeader');
  else sticky.removeClass('fixedHeader');
});
```

Example on Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4t7bfjon/

Comment: Ok Thank you, very much